# xml parse response from API xml request

Tags: python, xml, api

I'm trying to parse the xml api response to xml parse. This is the code

```
from xml.dom import minidom 
response = requests.post(url, data=request_xml.encode('utf8'), headers=headers)
xmldoc = minidom.parse(response.content)
```

But I'm not able to pass the response object. instead of response object if i pass xml file it works correctly.
xmldoc = minidom.parse('exmple.xml')
I want to parse the response object.

Can anyone please help me with this. I'm very greatful. thank you soo much in advance

Comment: Did you have a look at beautifulsoup?

Comment: in beautifilsoup, can i pass the json variables?

Comment: Where do you want to pass JSON variables? I'm pretty sure it can handle your use case.

Comment: I pass as json file as commandline argument to the python script. i access the variable as  col_names = data['header']. But i get the error now as TypeError: string indices must be integers. when i used minidom.parseString for to handle the response from api.

Comment: Unclear what you mean since minidom deals with XML, not JSON. Post a new question with details about your JSON and how it relates to your XML if at all.

Comment: do `print(response.content)` and share the output

Comment: Thank you soo much. I have made the new post, Please have look at it, hopefully now it is clear in the new post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, [minidom.parseString](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.parseString)

```py
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(response.content)
```

Comment: I pass json file as command line argument to have input of api informatio. If i try this parseString i get the error as   : col_names = data['header'] 
TypeError: string indices must be integers. Can you please help me with this

Comment: That's a different issue. Better post a new question regarding your JSON issue.

Comment: Okay thank you.. I asked it because after using the minidom.parseString(response.content) i get the type error for all the json variables